# Render all help text of a form_widget

Tags: forms, symfony4

I am rendering my form like this :

```
     {{ form_start(form) }}
     {{ form_widget(form) }}
     {{ form_end(form) }}
```

And I would like to render all help text of my form. 
I did this in my form builder

```
->add('ville',null,['attr' => ['class'=> 'form-control'], 'help'=>'helpExample'])
```

But I don't want to render each help text individually with `{{ form_help(form.ville) }}` (because as you see above I am rendering the whole form at once), is there any way to tell symfony to render all my help text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#help), help text

> by default is rendered below the field

And the default way to render the whole form at once is like this:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Your method using three lines is actually custom rendering the opening form tag, the form widgets, and then the closing form tag.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

You may want to try [`form_row()`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-row-form-view-variables) instead of `form_widget()` as it includes

> the field's label, errors, help and widget